# how build ilibjingle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, libjingle

I donwload ilibjinge from google code and have try to build it , but faild , who have told me how to build it ? or send me a ilibjingle project which have been built successfully so i can know what is wrong with my project. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

check out this following site:

http://shawnpark.tistory.com/183

http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/detail?id=111

Comment: sorry , i build it again  as your website said but meet lot of error as shown in my bloc [here](http://blog.csdn.net/shencaifeixia1/article/details/7801585), can you send me a successful project? thx